# My program not showing question or taking inputs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this simple Python  Maths Quiz Program for some reason sometimes when it is supposed to ask a question it doesn't display the question or allow any input and just says it is incorrect. The problem doesn't happen every time I run the program just sometimes.

```
import random

def RandomNum():
    import random
    ran= random.randint(1,10)
    return (ran)
def RanOperation():
    import random
    operation = ['+','-','x']
    RanOp = random.choice(operation)
    return (RanOp)


stop = False

while stop == False:
    Name= input("Hello, what is your name?").title()
    print("Hello,", Name, "Welcome to ARITHMETIC QUIZ")
    score=0
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(str(i)+".")
        num1 = RandomNum()
        num2 = RandomNum()
        operation = RanOperation()
        if operation == "+":
            ans = num1+num2
        elif operation == "-":
            if num1 > num2:
                ans = num1-num2
            elif num2>num1:
                ans = num2-num1
        elif operation == "x":
            ans = num1*num2
        if num1 > num2:
            num1 = str(num1)
            num2 = str(num2)
            Answer = int(input((num1+operation+num2+"=")))
        elif num2 > num1:
            num1 = str(num1)
            num2 = str(num2)
            Answer = int(input((num2+operation+num1+"=")))
        if Answer == ans:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        elif Answer != ans:
            print("The correct answer is", ans)
            print("Sorry this is incorrect!")
    length = int(len(Name))
    print("You got", score, "correct out of 10,", Name)
    File1 = open('Class_Scores.txt','a')
    File1.write("\n %-20s %10d" %(Name , score))
    File1.close()

    Ask = input("Do you want to continue? Y/N").upper()
    if Ask == "N":
        stop = True
    elif Ask == "Y":
        stop = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code's problem is that you do not always call the input:

> ```
> if num1 > num2:
>     num1 = str(num1)
>     num2 = str(num2)
>     Answer = int(input((num1+operation+num2+"=")))
> elif num2 > num1:
>     num1 = str(num1)
>     num2 = str(num2)
>     Answer = int(input((num2+operation+num1+"=")))
> ```

if `num1 == num` no input is done and the one from before is used (again).

You can solve it by changing one of them to `>=` or use an additional `else: ...`.

You can shorten/improve your code a lot if you

- do not `import random` multiple times
- use a dictionary to decide which function to call (reduces `if .. elif .. else`
- use input validation to avoid crashing on bad input
- [use `string.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) or even better [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) instead of python 2.7 % formatting
- use [`with open(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)  for file operations
- structure the code with some more functions

---

```
import random

def RanOperation():  
    return random.choice(['+','-','x']) 

def plus():
    # get both numbers with one random call
    a,b = random.choices(range(1,11),k=2) 
    return (a,b,a+b)

def minus():
    # only operation where a > b matters to not get negative results
    # sorting (low to high) and choosing b,a ensures a is at least b or more
    # the other operations are cummutative so its better to leave then unsorted
    # to train 8x4 as as well as 4x8
    b,a = sorted(random.choices(range(1,11),k=2) ) # a > b
    return (a,b,a-b)

def mult():
    a,b = random.choices(range(1,11),k=2)
    return (a,b,a*b)

def get_answer(a,operation,b):
    while True:
        try:
            k =  int(input( "{} {} {} = ".format(a,operation,b)))
            return k
        except Exception:
            print("Input a valid number.")
```

Usage:

```
# call which function for what ops?
# using    mapper["+"]() --> calls the plus() function - this reduces if/else's
mapper = {"-": minus, "+":plus, "x":mult}

while True:
    Name= input("Hello, what is your name?").title()
    print("Hello,", Name, "Welcome to ARITHMETIC QUIZ")
    score=0
    for i in range(10):
        print(str(i+1)+".")
        operation = RanOperation()
        a,b,ans = mapper[operation]()
        answer = get_answer(a,operation,b)

        if answer == ans:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("The correct answer is {:>10d}".format(ans))
            print("Sorry this is incorrect!")
    length = int(len(Name))
    print("You got", score, "correct out of 10,", Name)
    with open('Class_Scores.txt','a') as File1:
        File1.write("\n -{:20s} {:10d}".format(Name , score))

    Ask = input("Do you want to continue? Y/N").upper()
    if Ask == "N":
        break
```

Output:

```
Hello, what is your name?Enya
Hello, Enya Welcome to ARITHMETIC QUIZ
1.
10 - 5 = 5
Correct!
2.
8 - 6 = 9
The correct answer is          2
Sorry this is incorrect!
3.
10 - 2 = 8
Correct!
# ...snipp 4-9... 
10.
4 - 4 = 0
Correct!
You got 9 correct out of 10, Enya
Do you want to continue? Y/Nn
```

Comment: Thank! I can see you spent a lot of time on this so thanks! But since  i'm just a veginner i don't understand some of this so most likely won't use it. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your `input()` line only runs in two situations:

```
if num1 > num2:
```

and

```
elif num2 > num1:
```

What happens when `num1` and `num2` are the same? You won't enter the `if` block, because `num1 > num2` is `False`; And you won't enter the `elif` block, because `num2 > num1` is also `False`.

That means the `input()` won't run at all;

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very useful. That was stupid of me i guess